# Compute probability that mean is above a given value given samples

Tags: probability

Consider a Bernoulli distribution with an unknown mean parameter $p$. Let there be $n$ samples drawn (i.i.d.) from the distribution, denoted $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. I am trying to compute the probability that $p$ exceeds a given value $a$, that is
\begin{align}
\text{Pr}(p\ge a|X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)
\end{align}
I've written the following so far:
\begin{align}
\text{Pr}(p\ge a|X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n) &= \frac{\text{Pr}(p\ge a,X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)}{\text{Pr}(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)}\\
&=\frac{\prod_i\text{Pr}(p\ge a|X_i=x_1)\text{Pr}(X_i=x_1)}{\prod_i\text{Pr}(X_i=x_1)}
\end{align}
But where do I go from here? I want to write this in terms of things that we know.

---

**Edit**: If we compute the sample mean, then can't we compute/estimate the probability? I don't understand why we need a prior.

Comment: You cannot answer this question unless you have a prior distribution for $p$. Once you have a prior, you may use Bayes's rule. [Your computations are also not quite correct. For instance the $X_i$ are not independent (although they are conditionally independent given $p$.]

Comment: Just a suggestion... $\hat{p} = \bar{X}$ is the best estimator for $p$. By the central limit theorem, $\sqrt{n}(\hat{p} - p) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0, \hat{p}(1-\hat{p}))$; you can use this to get a rough estimate of the probability for large $n$.